# Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException issue in laravel when trying to sore the date

Tags: php, laravel, validation, exception, php-carbon

In my laravel based application, when creating new user accounts I'm trying to validate the birthday field. I have the following in my controller's store method

```
'date_of_birth'=>['required','date_format:m/d/Y',function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        
        $age=Carbon::parse($value)->diff(Carbon::now())->y;
        if($age<18||$age>70){
            $fail('Âge invalide. l\'âge devrait être 18-70');
        }
    },]
```

So the date format has to be m/d/Y and the age range has to be between 18-70.

Following is my form field

```
<div class="col-md-6 ">

    {!! Form::text('date_of_birth', null, array('placeholder' =>  __('texts.Date of birth'),'class' => 'form-control txt_txt','id'=>'datepicker')) !!}
        <span toggle="#dob-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar field-icon toggle-dob"></span>
        {!! $errors->first('date_of_birth', '<span class="help-block" role="alert">:message</span>') !!}
                
</div>
```

Now, whenever I put a date with an invalid date format like 18/12/1993, it kept giving me an error saying,

```
Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException
Could not parse '18/12/1993': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (18/12/1993) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character
```

How can I fix this and validate the date format and display the error message properly.

Comment: A word of advice, having spent what seems to be six months wrangling with dates. Even if it's a date of birth (ie. time is irrelevant), store it as a MySQL timestamp field, and cast it to a date in your User model. It will save you spending lines of code juggling things about, just as you are above.

Comment: Carbon uses the same rules as strtotime, which says `Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.`. Therefore, your date is being parsed as `m/d/Y`, and there is no 18th month

Comment: You'll need to use [createFromFormat](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation) instead

Comment: Or do a `$value = str_replace('/', '-', $value);` before using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your code from

```
$age=Carbon::parse($value)->diff(Carbon::now())->y;
```

to

```
$age=Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value)->diff(Carbon::now())->y;
```